# How can I convert python code into a parse tree and back into the original code?

Tags: python, parsing, tree, parse-tree

I would like to be able to convert python code (a string) into a parse tree, modify it at the tree level, then convert the tree into code (a string). When converting to a parse tree and back into code without any tree-level modification, the resulting code should match the original input code exactly.

I would like to use python for this. I found the `ast` and `parser` python modules, however ast trees lose information about the original code. As for the `parser` module, I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the parse tree or convert it into code.

Here's what I have so far.

```py
import ast
import astor # pip install astor
import parser

code = 'hi = 0'
ast_tree = ast.parse(code)
code_from_ast = astor.to_source(tree) # 'hi = 0\n'
parser_tree = parser.suite(code)
code_from_parser = ???
```

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow format, but I'd suggest you to search for "lossless syntax tree".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, the built-in `ast` module doesn't preserve many formatting information (whitespaces, comments, etc).
You need a Concrete Syntax Tree (e.g. LibCST) instead of Abstract Syntax Tree in this case. (You can install by `pip install libcst`)

Here is an example shows how to change the code from `hi = 0` to `hi = 2` by parse code as tree, mutating the tree and render tree back to source code.
More advanced usage could be found in https://libcst.readthedocs.io/

```
In [1]: import libcst as cst

In [2]: code = 'hi = 0'

In [3]: tree = cst.parse_module(code)

In [4]: print(tree)
Module(
    body=[
        SimpleStatementLine(
            body=[
                Assign(
                    targets=[
                        AssignTarget(
                            target=Name(
                                value='hi',
                                lpar=[],
                                rpar=[],
                            ),
                            whitespace_before_equal=SimpleWhitespace(
                                value=' ',
                            ),
                            whitespace_after_equal=SimpleWhitespace(
                                value=' ',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ],
                    value=Integer(
                        value='0',
                        lpar=[],
                        rpar=[],
                    ),
                    semicolon=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
                ),
            ],
            leading_lines=[],
            trailing_whitespace=TrailingWhitespace(
                whitespace=SimpleWhitespace(
                    value='',
                ),
                comment=None,
                newline=Newline(
                    value=None,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
    header=[],
    footer=[],
    encoding='utf-8',
    default_indent='    ',
    default_newline='\n',
    has_trailing_newline=False,
)

In [5]: class ModifyValueVisitor(cst.CSTTransformer):
   ...:     def leave_Assign(self, node, updated_node):
   ...:         return updated_node.with_changes(value=cst.Integer(value='2'))
   ...:

In [6]: modified_tree = tree.visit(ModifyValueVisitor())

In [7]: modified_tree.code
Out[7]: 'hi = 2'
```